# Embed website to facebook page tab

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-apps

I'm trying to embed this website "http://iconnectrto.net46.net/iConnect" inside facebook.

But i keep on getting this response http://iconnectrto.net46.net/iConnect takes too long to respond.

Canvas Page: apps.facebook.com/iconnect_rto
Canvas URL: iconnectrto.net46.net/iConnect/

What is the problem with my configuration? what do i need to change in my configuration ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled secure browsing, your page needs to be served via HTTPS. As your links only show HTTP, I guess this is your problem.